# How to convert Date string to a specific time zone

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs, date-conversion, moment-timezone

Given a Date string such as `var input = '2019-09-19 13:07:09'`

How can I convert that string to a different time zone? Knowing that `input` is in UTC.

I tried the following:

```
var input = '2019-09-19 13:07:09';
var convertTo = "US/Eastern";
var dateConverted = moment.tz(input, "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss", convertTo);
```

`dateConverted` remains the same as `input` after that code is executed.

I also tried:

```
var input = '2019-09-19 13:07:09';
var convertTo = "US/Eastern";
var inUTC = (moment(input).utc());
var dateConverted = moment.tz(inUTC, "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss", convertTo);
```

But in this case, the problem is that `inUTC` becomes `Thu Sep 19 2019 20:07:09 GMT+0000` after `(moment(input).utc());`

I expect the date to be converted to EST which would be `2019-09-19 09:07:09`

Any ideas how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert date to another timezone in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
var input = '2019-09-19 13:07:09';
var offUtc = moment.utc(input, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
var convertTo = "US/Eastern";
var dateConverted = offUtc.clone().tz(convertTo);
```