# How to convet UTC time to IST?

Tags: javascript, date, utc

I need to convert UTC time to IST using javascript, the sting is **13:18:30**, I have tried to convert this string to IST, but I couldn't do that, if anyone knows the answer or any idea help me to find out the answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert Date string to a specific time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58018727/how-to-convert-date-string-to-a-specific-time-zone)

Answer (score -1):

You have to use moment js package for this purpose. Here is the example-

```
import moment from "moment-timezone";

var input = new Date();
var utcTime = moment.utc(input).format();
var istTime = moment(utcTime).tz("Asia/Kolkata").format();

console.log(istTime);
console.log(utcTime);
```

Comment: There is no need to use a library, plain JS is sufficient (e..g `new Date().toLocaleString('default',{timeZone:'Asia/Kolkata'})`). There are many alternatives to moment.js.